# overriding lightning:input default error format

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

i have `lightning:input type="date"  dateStyle="short"` in my component, i want to override the default error message  `Your entry does not match the allowed format M/d/yyyy.` to `format must be mm/dd/yyyy` for that i used `onblur` handler. it works but override error message persisting in valid scenario also.

1. if i enter wrong format it shows override message then after change to correct format then handle fires and still validity shows `false`. override error message persisting, can you find where am i made wrong.

**cmp**

```
            <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
        access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="persondob" type="Date"></aura:attribute>
<lightning:input aura:id="dob" type="date" dateStyle="short" label="Date of Birth" value="{!v.persondob}" 
                 messageWhenValueMissing="Date of Birth is Mandatory" required="true" class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-p-horizontal_x-small" onblur="{! c.handleBlur }"/>
```

**cmpcontroller**

```
({
 handleBlur : function(component,event,helper){
    var dobcmp = component.find("dob"),
    chckvalididty = dobcmp.get("v.validity");
    console.log(chckvalididty.valid); // it gives false when 1st enter wrong format then i changed to correct format still shows
    if(!chckvalididty.valid){
        dobcmp.setCustomValidity('format must be mm/dd/yyyy');
    }else{
        dobcmp.setCustomValidity('') ;
    }
    dobcmp.reportValidity();
},
})
```

[image]
[image]

2. if i comment `\\dobcmp.setCustomValidity('format must be mm/dd/yyyy');`  in controller, `chckvalididty.valid` gives `false` for wrong format then shows default error message, after i changed to correct format it gave 'true` then error message disappear. 
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before checking `validity`, you need to get rid of custom `validityMessage` that you set earlier. If that message exists, even if your value is valid it will say its not valid because of older message you set.

So is valid internally is

```
valid = isComponentValid && isCustomMessageNotBlank()
```

Fix:

```
 ({
        handleBlur : function(component,event,helper){

            var dobcmp = component.find("dob");
            dobcmp.setCustomValidity('') ;
            var chckvalididty = dobcmp.get("v.validity");
            console.log(chckvalididty.valid); // it gives false when 1st enter wrong format then i changed to correct format still shows
            if(!chckvalididty.valid){
                dobcmp.setCustomValidity('format must be mm/dd/yyyy');
            }else{
                dobcmp.setCustomValidity('') ;
            }
            dobcmp.reportValidity();
        },
    })
```

Comment: thank you save my day.

Comment: @sdandamud1 can you mark it as accepted, it will help others with similar query reach solution faster

Comment: yes i did the up vote, is any thing i need to do for accept?

Comment: There would be a checkbox beside the answer.